# How to reverse linked list

Tags: c

i'm trying to reverse a linked list returning the reversed list.

```
typedef struct lligada 
{

     int valor;
     struct lligada *prox;

} *LInt;
```

This is my funtion :

```
LInt reverseL (LInt l){

    LInt aux = malloc (sizeof(struct lligada));

    if(l != NULL){

            while( l -> prox != NULL){
                aux = l-> prox;
                aux -> prox = l;
                l = l-> prox;
            }


    }

    else return NULL;

    return aux;
}
```

Can you help me please ?

I've tried doing this :

```
if(l != NULL){

        if(l -> prox == NULL) {
            aux = l;
        }

        else{
            while( l -> prox != NULL){
                aux = l-> prox;
                aux -> prox = l;
                l = l-> prox;
            }
            aux -> prox = l;
        }

}
```

Is that a good idea ?

Comment: In what way does your solution not work?

Comment: First of all, your malloc is useless and *probably* leaks memory

Comment: OT: do not hide pointers in `typedef` statements

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding:  use meaningful variable names.  A variable (or parameter) name should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)  What are `l` `aux` `proc` supposed to represent?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the call to malloc is useless in this case and it is a memory leak.

This snippet doesn't work because you create an endless loop between the first two elements

```
if (l != NULL) 
{
    if (l->prox == NULL) 
    {
        aux = l;
    }
    else 
    {
        while (l->prox != NULL) 
        {
            aux = l->prox;
            aux->prox = l;
            l = l->prox;
        }
        aux->prox = l;
    }
}
```

You can change like so

```
LInt new_head, aux;
new_head = NULL;
while (l != NULL) 
{
    aux = l->prox;
    l->prox = new_head;
    new_head = l;
    l = aux;
}

return new_head;
```